# fancyhdr clearing first page of a chapter

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr

Hi have already a working fancyheader, but it is also showing on the chapter beginning which I want to avoid (see attachment).

```
 \pagestyle{plain} % reset page numbering to 1,2,3,..
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
 \setcounter{page}{1} 


 \fancypagestyle{plain}
 \fancyhf{}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead{}
 \fancyhead[L]{\textit{\sffamily\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}}
 \fancyhead[R]{\textit{\sffamily\thepage}}
 \fancyfoot[C]{}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
```

[image: chapter begining]

**Basically the cfoot ist not applying for the first page of a chapter.**

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! In order for others to help more efficiently, please consider providing a minimal working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Your syntax of `\fancypagestyle` is wrong: it should have two arguments. A MWE is definitely needed.

Comment: You don't need `\fancypagestyle` here at all. I you just use `\pagestyle{fancy}`, it will all work properly as that style will not affect the first page of chapters. Also, you are unnecessarily complicating things. `fancyhdr` includes facilities for different stuff on odd and even pages - you don't need to test the page numbers yourself. And `\pagenumbering{arabic}` sets the numbering to 1,2,3... and the page number back to 1 so the other commands are unnecessary.

Comment: Two almost identical questions, both solvable by *correctly use `fancypagestyle`* A solution here would just be the same as i gave to your other question. I vote to close.